# combine a list of dictionaries with one key value match

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

```
listofdicts = [
{
    "if-e0": "e0",
    "ip-add-e0": "192.168.1.1",
    "name": "host1"
},
{
    "if-e1": "e1",
    "ip-add-e1": "192.168.2.1",
    "name": "host1"
},
{
    "if-e1": "e1",
    "ip-add-e1": "172.16.1.1",
    "name": "host2"
},
{
    "if-e2": "e2",
    "ip-add-e2": "172.16.2.1",
    "name": "host2"
}]
```

Expected Result:

```
listofdicts = [
{
    "if-e0": "e0",
    "ip-add-e0": "192.168.1.1",
    "if-e1": "e1",
    "ip-add-e1": "192.168.2.1",
    "name": "host1"
},
{
    "if-e1": "e1",
    "ip-add-e1": "172.16.1.1",
    "if-e2": "e2",
    "ip-add-e2": "172.16.2.1",
    "name": "host2"
}]
```

Have been trying to make this work but no luck yet, actual list has more than 60K dicts with unique and matching hosts.

It could be easier to solve but for me, it's been a nightmare from past few hrs.

Appreciate your assistance.

Regards,
Avinash

Comment: Hi Avinash! Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting to make your question formatting clearer. It helps other understand your code and your issue better and they will be able to help you a lot quicker.

Comment: ok, have already fixed the formatting, still not ok? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kolay.Ne Hi, Hey guys,
It did work with a very basic catch. Graph method is fantastic to solve it although I used below approach n that worked:

```
for d in listofdicts:
    x = listofdicts.index(d)
    for y in range(len(listofdicts)):
        k = 'name'
        if y != x and y < len(listofdicts):
            if listofdicts[x][k] == listofdicts[y][k]:
                dc = copy.deepcopy(listofdicts[y])
                listofdicts[x].update(dc)
                listofdicts.remove(dc)
```

Could be other approaches to solve it, im sure pathonic way will be just couple of lines, this solved my problem for the job in hand.

Thank you to kolay.Ne for responding quickly and trying to assist,  and graph method is fantastic as well, requires professional coding and for sure that will be more scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Graph theory seems to be helpful here.

To solve this, you need to build a graph, where each vertex relates to one dictionary from your input list.

There should be an edge between two vertices if there is a common key-value pair in the corresponding dictionaries (more specifically, for dictionaries `d1` and `d2` there should be an edge if `len(set(d1.items()).intersection(d2.items())) != 0` or, simpler, if `set(d1.items()).intersection(d2.items())`. The condition means there is at least one key-value pair in the intersection of the sets of items of `d1` and `d2`).

After the graph is built, you need to find all the connectivity components (that's a pretty simple DFS (depth-first search), you can google it if you're not familiar with graph algorithms). Each connectivity component's dictionaries should be combined in one: there should be one resulting dictionary per component. The list of these resulting dictionaries is your answer.

Here is an example of how you combine some dictionaries:

```py
connectivity_component_dicts = [{...}, ...]
resulting_dict = {**d for d in connectivity_component_dicts}
# Note that the greater the index of `d` in `connectivity_component_dicts`,
# the higher priority its keys have if there are same keys in some dicts.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, going to try it.

Comment: @AvinashRai, good luck. Feel free to ask for help if you get stuck or realise you don't understand something in my explanation

Comment: Hi @kolay.Ne, yes it did work. This was a fantastic way to solve although i tried a diffrent approach

Answer (score -2):

```
a = []

for i in listofdicts:
    if i["name"] not in a:
        a.append(i["name"])
        print(i)
```

Comment: Seems to neither always solve the problem (there was nothing about `name` keys in the statement) nor even produce the expected result

Comment: Thank you so much for quick reply, but it overwrites one the interfaces for an instance host1 having its e1 missing in new list a, produces following: <b>{'if-e0': 'e0', 'ip-add-e0': '192.168.1.1', 'name': 'host1'} <b>,  and host2 having e2 missing.